# React - How to pass an attribute to a component received as argument

Tags: reactjs

I have a component A that receives a component B as argument and renders it.

I'd like the component B - which I receive in component A as an argument - to call a function in component A.

So I would have to pass an attribute to component B, but I can't because I render it as an argument:

```
<ComponentABody>
  {ComponentB}
</ComponentABody>
```

What I'd like to do could be exemplified as:

```
<ComponentABody>
  {ComponentB attribute={componentAFunction} }
</ComponentABody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do not use cloneElement or any sort of hack. Use the React [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) API, it is what it is designed for.

Component A will render a context provider, with the function [you want component B to execute] passed  down as a context value

Component B will read the context value, take the function [passed by Component A] from it, and call it when needed

Example:

```
// ---------------
// --- Context ---
// ---------------
type ComponentAContextValue = {
  myFunction
}

const ComponentAContext = React.createContext<
  ComponentAContextValue | null
>(null);

// -------------------
// --- Component A ---
// -------------------

const ComponentA = ({ children }) => {
  const someFunction = () => {}

  const contextValue = React.useMemo(() => ({
    myFunction: someFunction
  }))

  return (
    <ComponentAContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
      {children}
    </ComponentAContext.Provider>
  )
}

// -------------------
// --- Component B ---
// -------------------

const ComponentB = ({ children }) => {
  const contextValue = React.useContext(ComponentAContext);

  const handleEvent = () => {
    contextValue?.myFunction()
  }

  return (
    <div>{children}</div>
  );

}

// -------------------
// --- Usages --------
// -------------------


// valid usage
const componentB = <ComponentB>foo</ComponentB>

<ComponentA>{componentB}</ComponentA>

// also valid usage
<ComponentA>
  <ComponentB>
    Foo
  </ComponentB>
</ComponentA>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<ComponentABody>
  <ComponentB attribute={componentAFunction} />
</ComponentABody>
```

you can write it this way, if you want componentB in componentA, and pass its attributes.
To access component, use `props.children`

Comment: It doesn't work.